# A sub which is triggered "OnSave" works with Excel 2013 but fails with Excel 365 - run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub in VBA which is triggered by a button click and it is also called from "Workbook_BeforeSave"

```
Sub create()
Dim actWb As Workbook
Dim prjSh As Worksheet
Dim forcastSh As Worksheet
Dim prjData As Range
Dim lRow As Double
Dim lCol As Double
Dim prjNumGrp As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Dim colPRJID, colCOMDT, colEXD, excVal As String
Set forcastSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Forecast")
cleanSheet forcastSh
Dim prjRw As Double
    Set actWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set prjSh = actWb.Worksheets("PROJECTS")
    ' get the column letter for the column header
    colPRJID = ColIndex("Project Group")
    lRow = prjSh.Cells(prjSh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = prjSh.Cells(2, prjSh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set prjData = prjSh.Range(prjSh.Cells(3, 1), prjSh.Cells(lRow, lCol))
    For Each rw In prjData.Rows
        prjNumGrp = Trim(prjSh.Range(colPRJID & rw.Row).value)
    Next rw
End Sub
```

This works fine when I am running it on my Laptop with Excel 2013. It also runs when my client runs it with Excel 360 (with button click or file save), but suddenly fails when Excel try to auto save the file.

The error it gives is

> "run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed"

This is where the debugger take me to `prjNumGrp = Trim(prjSh.Range(colPRJID & rw.Row).value)`

Since I don'e have the Excel 365 installed it is bit difficult to debug this but still it looks illogical. I would appreciate any help here.

P.S. - The above piece of code is only a part of the original code, as the original one is too big, I have copied only the relevant part here.

Comment: `Dim colPRJID, colCOMDT, colEXD, excVal As String` these are all implicit `Variant` except  `excVal` which is actually a `String`. What is the value of `colPRJID` when you get the error?

Comment: yeah, I understand that, it is just an old habit of writing them in a line. The value of `colPRJID` is "C" when this fails.

Comment: Unless `rw.Row` equals 0 I can't see where the error must be

Comment: That is also my worry, and it doesn't fail normally, only when the sub is triggered due to Auto Save, I am not sure what is different there and as I mentioned I don't have Excel 360 to debug it further.

Comment: I cannot see a specific problem either, however, I've had similar problems on old code written for 2013 that I could not see a problem with, and I stopped using Range unless the sheet in question was active, changing to Cells() eliminated the problem .... I was too lazy to dig further and just wanted it to go away - just thought it might be worth a mention (with no logic behind it)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Tin, I too had read somewhere that Cell() can fix the problem. I will try that if I fail to get any solution here :)

Comment: What is `rw.Row` should it not just be rw?

Comment: possibly should be `.cells(colPRJID , rw).value`

Comment: For good practice you should use `Dim rw As Range`, as it's not defined anywhere as 'Range'.

Comment: @ShaiRado, oh ya, I didn't notice rw was a range, I thought it was a counter.